# Inserting some Python list into a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I'm trying to insert some list into a SQL Server database.

I have tried this so far:

```
trdcode = trdcode[1:]
ltp = ltp[1:]
high = high[1:]

datatable = [tuple(trdcode),tuple(ltp),tuple(high)]
query = "INSERT INTO test (TRADINGCODE, LTP, HIGH) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
cursor.execute(query, datatable)
connection.commit()
```

But I'm getting an error:

[image]

The data type in SQL Server for those columns is `VARCHAR` and the list elements are `str`.

How can I solve this error? Or is there any alternative way to perform this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method cur.execute won't iterate over a list a values, you should try using cur.executemany().

So first step would be to construct a list of tuples. Each tuple will be a row to enter in the database:

```
rows = [(trdcode[i], ltp[i], high[i]) for i in range(0, len(ltp))]
```

Then you pass this list to the cursor.executemany method:

```
cursor.executemany(query, rows)
connection.commit()
```

You can read more on cursors [here](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.Cursor.executemany)

Comment: I tried this:
`cursor.executemany(query, [(r,) for r in datatable])`
And it's saying:
**('The SQL contains 3 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')**

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension, just pass the list of tuples (datatable in your case) as is. I have edited my answer to be more explicit.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. After doing this:
`cursor.executemany(query, datatable)`
`connection.commit()`
I'm getting this error:
**('The SQL contains 3 parameter markers, but 355 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')**

Comment: Just noticed the datable list doesn't represent rows appropriately. Updated the answer once more.

Comment: Thanks a ton man! You are a real hero. Thanks again for spending your valuable time.